# What is the function of the soft sign (Ь) in Russian?

Tags: phonetics, orthography, consonants, russian, palatalization

After some searching, I'm still unsure about what function the soft sign (Ь) performs in Russian. I have read that it indicates declension, palatisation, and iotation in different contexts, but with limited understanding of what the latter two concepts mean.

I suppose the function of the sign would also explain why it is variously represented as *y* or *'* in Latin script.

Comment: We recently had [a similar question](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/164/) at Ukrainian.SE. The phonology of "soft sign" is equal between the Russian and Ukrainian languages. Briefly, the "soft sign" has derived from an ancient short "i" vowel, but then reduced to a phonological aspect (palatalization) that affects the preceding consonant.

Comment: The function is being a letter (changing the meaning of a word), the effect is softening the preceding vowel.

Comment: @IllidanS4 the preceding consonant

Comment: @Anixx Of course, thanks, I always mix them up in English...

Comment: @IllidanS4 you'd need to explain what 'softening' means.  Otherwise, you're just saying 'the soft sign indicates softening'.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

WARNING: The question is sooo many-sided, it is very wide and can be split into at least 3 different questions. I'll answer it all, don't tell me later that you haven't been warned the answer would be long.

First of all, this letter *has no sound* of its own. The main function of the soft sign <Ь> in Russian is to change the sound of the consonant letter which stands before it. In Russian, most consonant sounds can be paired into couples of non-palatalized ("hard") vs. palatalized ("soft"). In English no consonant sound has such a pair; most of them are non-palatalized and for English native speakers it is usually a hard part of studying Russian pronunciation to learn how to pronounce those sounds palatalized.

[Palatalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palatalization_(phonetics)) (P) can easily be explained, but is very hard to produce with the tongue (for those who have no such thing as P in their native language). The main idea behind it is that palatalized consonants (PC) are bi-focal: beside the main focus of articulation, the tongue also makes the second focus touching the *palate* with its back, hence the name. For example, Russian <**C**> is approximately like the English  [s], with the tip of the tongue nearly touching somewhere near the upper teeth, but in the Russian <**CЬ**> [sʲ] the tongue also touches the palate with its back adding a [j]-like air to [s]. Still, [sʲ] is *one sound*, you can drawl, sustain it for a long time and all that time it will sound the same.  (Not all palatalized consonants can be sustained, of course, just as not all *consonants* can be sustained.)

Another trick is that the P of a consonant sound can be shown not only with the soft sign, but also with vowel letters. They are also paired into the ones that cause P (they are called "iotizing" — that is, 'adding the [j] air') and the ones that don't (called "non-iotizing"). The pairs are like this:

```
Non-iotizing vowel letters:     a  э  ы  о  у
                                |  |  |  |  | 
Iotizing vowel letters:         я  е  и  ё  ю
[1]
```

The idea behind the iotizing vowels is that when they stand after a consonant letter they palatalize it and then they are read as the corresponding non-iotizing letters. For example:

```
мал [mal] - small
мял [mʲal] - (he) crumpled
[2]
```

In the beginning of words and after another vowel letter the iotizing letters are pronounced as [j] + the corresponding non-iotizing letter:

```
ясно [ˈjasnə] - clear
бояться [bɐ'jatsə] - to be afraid
(yeah, here the soft sign doesn't affect any sound)
[3]
```

But what if we need to write a word in which a consonant is followed by a distinct sound [j] + a vowel, like a 3-sound word [bʲju] - 'I beat'? We cannot write it as `бьйу`, because (another trick is coming up!)
    the combination <Й> + a non-iotizing vowel letter are (hahaha!)
    forbidden in spelling of Russian words which were not borrowed from another language. [4]

If we write it as `бю`, then according to [2] it will be read as [bʲu], a **2**-sound word... The only correct way to write that word is `бью`, because

```
after <Ь> the iotized vowel letters
are read as [j] + the corresponding
non-iotizing letters:

льёт [lʲjot] - he/she pours
пью [pʲju] - I drink
```

And at last, differentiating the gender of nouns with the help of <Ь>. In Russian, most feminine nouns end in [a], but there are lots of them that end in a consonant. In the latter case a soft sign must be written at the end of the word (ahaha!) *irrespective* of whether the final consonant is actually palatalized or not!

```
(masc.) мел [mʲel] - chalk 
(fem.) мель [mʲelʲ] - shoal
(fem.) мышь [mɨʂ] - mouse (ends in a
non-P consonant!)
(fem.) ложь [loʂ] - a lie (ends in a
non-P consonant!)
```

This is actually everything you asked about! Naturally, there are other issues with <Ь>, like differentiating some verb forms where it doesn't in any way affect the pronunciation, or using it before non-iotizing letters in borrowed words, not to mention its historical usage problems, but that is another tale.

Comment: > _the combination <Й> + a non-iotizing vowel letter are (hahaha!) forbidden in spelling of Russian words_: Note though that although the following words are originally not Russian, they are widely used these days: йод, йогурт, район — they obviously break this rule.

Comment: @Ruslan - You're absolutely right, but note, that in the last paragraph I wrote that such a combination is allowed in borrowed words only, and most Europeans will at once understand the words you enumerated are not Russian since they are internationalsims. And if native speakers don't perceive some borrowed words as borrowing, those words don't stop to be such because of that. However a Russian would be sure that words _деньги, кровать, корабль, царь, колбаса, хлеб_ are original Russian and Slavic words, they still remain in fact borrowings. We're talking about real facts here, aren't we? ))

Comment: Two things threw me in this writeup; the rest is very helpful.  (1) I *can't* make the standard English "s" sound with my tongue tip *touching* anything.  (2) The softened "m" sound seems to me to be indistinguishable from hard "m" as long as it is "drawled" (that is, it can only be distinguished after the lips open), by contrast with your description of a softened "s" sound.  Comment?

Comment: @bytebuster - Thank you very much for your corrections! I hadn't slept for too long before I wrote this and my computer is so slow and lagging... Good proof-reading has always been the best secutity.

Comment: @Wildcard: The description of palatalization in this answer seems to be based on articulation, not perception, so it may well be that [mʲ] is not easily to distinguish from [m~mˠ] when there is no preceding vowel and the consonant has not yet been released. But examining the mouths of Russian speakers could show that they still are doing something different while they are pronouncing the consonant.

Comment: @Wildcard: The example of [sʲ] was presumably chosen because its is a consonant that can be held with a sustained sound. Not all consonants can be audibly sustained at all (you can't do that to a voiceless stop like /p/, for example; if you try to sustain it before the release, you'll just get a longer period of silence) but Russian still has a palatalization contrast for p.

Comment: @sumelic, yes, so I surmised (for my point #2).  For the other, I think it is just a genuine error, but it did make me wonder how precise and accurate is the description of palatalization if the description of the physical tongue motions needed just to make the "s" sound are inaccurate.  :)

Comment: @Wildcard - Yours is a question worth to be asked here as a separate question of its own. As you can see, answering the OP's question took me  650+ words. The position of the tounge tip _wasn't_ what the OP asked, and also when speaking of sibilants the tounge cannot touch _anything_ since there's the flow of air between the tongue and that something. Have you ever thought how people are able to talk whispering? While whispering the vocal cords never move, so the difference between the voiced and voiceless gets neutralised, although phonticians state it's important for distinguishing words...

Comment: @Wildcard - The same goes about people speaking with stuffed nose when nasals and oral consonants sound the same people still can understand one another. What i mean is, the question was about a symbol of a writing system, <Ь>, about a phonetic characterisic of consonants in a language, (palatalization), and about a category of graphic symbols in a language, (Russian iotizing vowel letters). I told him everything I could about them three and it became a magnum opus. Please, admit, if I had written about _all_ the peculiarities of theirs, it would have become a treatise on universal phonology.

Comment: I would love to read such a treatise from you.  :D  But you don't have to write a treatise to be sure your brief statements are accurate—I will propose a slight edit.

Comment: Something I wonder about, does the English word "pew" sound to a Russian speaker more like "пью" or "пю"? Or can it sound like either, or in between?

Comment: @sumelic - "Pew" /pjuː/ will definitely sound like "пью". Generally speaking, the syllable "пю" is very rare in Russian and sounds weird for a Russian ear, it can be found in just a handful of borrowed words, like "пюпитр" - 'music stand'.

Comment: This isn't directly relevant to the answer itself, but it gave me a hearty chuckle while teaching me something. Thank you!

Comment: This is hardly related, but what system is the most veracious for representing Russian in Latin script? I'm willing to ask this as an additional question. @YellowSky

Comment: @MadBanners - I think it's [BGN/PCGN romanization system for Russian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BGN/PCGN_romanization_of_Russian).

Comment: How should the soft and hard signs be Romanised? @YellowSky

Comment: @MadBanners - With `’` and `"` correspondingly. Haven't you read the wiki article I gave a link to?

Comment: I did, just wondering what your personal opinion was, I suppose. @YellowSky

Comment: Apparently, лож and ложь are homophones? That's news to me, been learning Russian for maybe twelve years and I pronounce them distinctly!

Comment: @Wilson - Yes, they are, the Russian [ʂ] and [ʐ] are always "hard", they have no "soft" counterparts. By "лож" you mean the genitive plural form of "ложе" (bed) and "ложа" (theater box; Masonic lodge), don't you?

Comment: Yes, that's the лож I meant. Will it be problem if I pronounce ложь as [loʂʲ] and лож as [loʂˠ]?

Comment: @Wilson - Both words are pronounced the same way, as [loʂˠ] (I can see now I made a mistake in my answer above, surely _ложь_ is pronounced [loʂ] or [loʂˠ], I'll correct it). Naturally, it's up to you how to pronounce words, but I wouldn't recommend palatalizing [ʂ] and [ʐ], or pronouncing them as the English [ʃ] and [ʒ]. If you do that, it won't affect the others' ability to understand what you say, but it will definitely add a strong foreign accent to your speech, which should be avoided as much as possible, since _too much_ foreign accent can obscure your speech for a native Russian ear.

Answer (score 4):

From the point of view of the spelling, Ь simply means "the previous consonant should be palatalized". See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palatalization_(phonetics) to learn what palatalization is, it's a lengthy topic (P.S. Yellow Sky has a nice overview). Most consonsants in Russian come in pairs: palatalized/non-palatalized (also called soft/hard). Additionally, before vowels, Ь means "y" (Воробьев => Vorobyov)

When it comes to morphology, -Ь is often found in cases where we have a null ending in words whose stems end in a palatalized consonant, example: путь. Also found in 2nd declension in nominative/accusative cases (of feminine gender) for historical reasons: ночь (consonant Ч is always palatalized, so no need to have Ь as a palatalization marker, but we still do).

-ь is also found, for example, as a morphological unit, in imperative word forms: брось! i.e. it tells that C is palatalized, witch matches with the palatalizedness of С in the original infinitive: бросить

In some cases, like -ешь in verbs (for 2nd person), the spelling is just historical, and Ь there doesn't mean anything anymore.

**So, in a nutshell, you can think of Ь as yet another palatalizing vowel (similar to Е and И), except it's not actually pronounced, yet still has influence on surrounding sounds.**